# Application works only in PC on which was created

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, crash, exe

As in topic - problem is that, when I copy file to another PC, exe file doesn't work, but works on mine without problems. Also my friend's exe (from the same project) works on my and him PC.

Error:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
<EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
<Level>2</Level> 
<Task>100</Task> 
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-03-17T15:29:17.000000000Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>38758</EventRecordID> 
<Channel>Application</Channel> 
<Computer>PC1</Computer> 
<Security /> 
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>VP.exe</Data> 
<Data>2014.3.17.1</Data> 
<Data>532713e2</Data> 
<Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data> 
<Data>6.1.7601.18229</Data> 
<Data>51fb1116</Data> 
<Data>e0434352</Data>
```

System.TypeInitializationException

Comment: Probably a dll that needs to be included in the package. If you included any such thing, copy it into a zip with your exe.

Comment: Well, all dlls and other packages are the same on him and mine pc. I copy exe file into his Debug folder (so thats 100% guarantee that all dlls are in right folder)

Comment: Also, make sure the other computer has the redistributable installed

Comment: Im not sure why only this project doesn't work. All other new projects works. Only this exe doesn't

Comment: Oh i just saw your comment. I thought you were saying it worked on both of your computers but not on a different computer.

Comment: Nope, my exe from this project works only in my PC (all other projects works great). His exe (from all projects) works on all pc where we install or simply copy it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49888/discussion-between-wreithkassan-and-user13657)